# a problem on unimodular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

A unimodular matrix is a matrix with integer entries and having determinant $1$ or $-1$. If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, write down a necessary and sufficient condition such that there exists a unimodular matrix of order $2$ whose first row is the vector ($m, n$)

---

totally stuck.can anybody help.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect by "unimodular matrix of order 2" you mean a $2 \times 2$ unimodular matrix.  (Having order 2 means something different than this.)

So let's write down a matrix as specified in the problem:
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix} m & n \\ a & b \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $\det(M) = bm - an$.  In order for $bm - an = \pm 1$, $m$ and $n$ cannot have a common factor (why?).

Conversely, suppose that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime (i.e. have no common factor).  Can we always find integers $a,b$ such that $bm - an = \pm 1$?  Hint: use the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Try $gcd(m,n)=1$. If it is 1 there are ways to solve $mx+ny=1$ in integers $x,y$.

If it is not 1, there is no way to complete the matrix to have unimodular.